# Below query doesnt give me expected result please help me out

Tags: mysql, subquery, in-subquery

The select query has to display seperate row for every value it gets
but on executing this query it yields only first value from the sub query used in IN clause.

```
    SELECT prod_id FROM tbl_product WHERE tbl_product.prod_status = 1 AND 
tbl_product.is_excluded = 0 AND tbl_product.prod_stock_qty > 0 
AND tbl_product.prod_id IN (SELECT rel_prod_ids 
FROM tbl_product_relations WHERE prod_id = '6058')
```

The subquery yields the Comma seperated values

Could someone help me out to find me the resolution of this?

Comment: can you please post your table definitions?

Comment: what is the type of rel_prod_ids ? and if you run the sub query alone what its return ?

Comment: @om-the-eternity What CSV? When CSV? please rewrite your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select find_in_set(123, '123,12345,123456');  <-- return 1
select find_in_set(123, '1234,12345,123456'); <-- return 0
```

This function is quite slow and beware over the performance ...

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JOIN` instead of a `IN`

```
SELECT p.prod_id
FROM tbl_product p JOIN tbl_product_relations pr ON p.prod_id = pr.rel_prod_ids
WHERE p.prod_status = 1
    AND p.is_excluded = 0
    AND p.prod_stock_qty > 0
    AND r.prod_id = '6058'
```

Comment: I get the CSV from subquery so i cant use JOIN

Comment: Your comments does not explain why you cannot use join, this join query seems nice.